# Aplicações Vuejs com erro no build repentinamente

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Bom dia a todos, hoje pela manhã fiz um hotfix e o mesmo fez o build da forma esperada porém quando fui melhorar o hotfix e fazer o build, um erro apareceu no build

`TypeError: ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function`

Depois de algumas tentativas de sanar o erro sem sucesso, fui tentar executar o build nas outras aplicações vuejs sem efetuar nenhuma mudança e todas deram o mesmo erro, aguem mais está passando por isso e se sim, conseguiu resolver ou saberia como me ajudar a resolver?

```
ERROR  TypeError: ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function
```

TypeError: ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function
at getOriginalErrorStack (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/core/extractWebpackError.js:31:29)
at extractError (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/core/extractWebpackError.js:22:20)
at Array.map ()
at processErrors (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/core/transformErrors.js:31:17)
at FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin.displayErrors (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/friendly-errors-plugin.js:97:29)
at doneFn (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/friendly-errors-plugin.js:57:14)
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :18:1)
at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
at node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:304:22
at Compiler.emitRecords (node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
at node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:298:10
at node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14
at _next0 (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :16:1)
at eval (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :24:1)
at node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:115:7
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :20:1)

Comment: Estou com o mesmo erro aqui

Comment: Aqui ocorre quando eu coloco as configurações do Vue Apollo no arquivo main.ts. Se eu comento essas configurações não dá erro de build

Comment: Eu consegui resolver aqui. Pelo que vi era uma dependencia faltando, o Apollo Vue precisava de um outro pacote. Descobri isso apagando a pasta node_modules e rodando yarn install foi onde vi os alertas no console.

Comment: @AlexandreHeinen sabe qual o pacote?

Comment: No meu caso era um específico para trabalhar com graphql

Comment: Eu consegui descobrir apagando a pasta node_modules e executando o comando yarn install, ou npm install, apareceram alguns alertas no console e era dizendo que o Vue Apollo não encontrou os pacotes. Você pode tentar aí e se aparecer algum aviso que um pacote está dependendo de outro tente fazer a instalação dele(s)

Comment: Na verdade está dando isso cada vez que tem algum erro no código. Chato demais isso, pq não sei o que ta errado, então preciso ir desfazendo todas as alterações pra descobrir o erro

Comment: pois é, meus erros eram em uma dependência de outro pacote, o tal do @soda, tentei deletando o node_modules recriando o package-lock e tal e nada funcionava, porém, assim como o erro apareceu, o erro sumiu, sem fazer absolutamente nada, não mudei nada e o erro sumiu.

Answer (score 0):

Com o npm run serve o app funciona normalmente.

Aqui resolveu com esses parametros. Experimenta isso:

no seu package.json adicione em devDependencies:
"error-stack-parser": "2.0.6"

ainda no package.json crie uma nova chave :
"resolutions": {
"error-stack-parser": "2.0.6"
}

Comment: Pow, não tentei o "resolutions": { "error-stack-parser": "2.0.6" } não só tentei instalando o "error-stack-parser": "2.0.6" e não havia funcionado, porém assim como o erro surgiu, o erro sumiu sem mudar absolutamente nada, simplesmente parou de dar erro.